# Entity Framework 4.3 one to one foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, relationship, entity-framework-4.3, one-to-one

I am hoping some one will provide me with more insight after spending countless hours configuring the data model of an existing database. I have the following database structure

```
User (Table)
    UserID  (P.K Identity int)
    UserName (nvarchar)

UserSetting (Table)
    UserSettingsID (P.K Identity int)
    UserSettingsUserID (F.K of User.UserID)
```

In the model, I have a property UserSetting for user entity and User property on the usersetting entity.

In the user setting entity type configuration;

```
 this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
     .WithMany(t => t.UserSetting)
     .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserSettingsUserID)
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The above will only work (this is the only solution I have at the moment) if I make the UserSetting as ICollection in the user entity. I have tried setting foreign key attributes and almost anything I can find on the net but no luck. This is my first time coding with entity framework using repository pattern and unit of work.

Comment: To enforce the 1 to 1 relationship in the DB in your schema definition, you need a unique constraint on the `UserSettingUserID` column within the `UserSetting` Table. If I am not mistaken, unique constraints will only be supported in EF 5.0: http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2010/09/13/entity-framework-5.0---not-quite-there-yet.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @DannyVarod: Unique constraints won't be supported in EF 5.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx It was on the road map last year but didn't make it into EF 5.

Answer (score 2):

Check this guy's blog for a solution:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Basically:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
HasRequired(us => us.UserSetting).
WithMany().
HasForeignKey(u => u.UserSettingId);
```

Pay close attention to how he structured the `User` class properties and the properties' names. Names must match accordingly.

By the way: decorating the entities with data annotations is way easier than with the Fluent API.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this schema for a 1 to 0..1 entity mapping in EF 4.x:**

```
Table Users
    UserID int, PK, Identity
    UserName nvarchar

Table UserSettings
    UserID int, PK, non-Identity, FK to Users
    Settings nvarchar(max) or any other type
```

**Or this schema for a 1 to 1 entity mapping in EF 4.x (split the table into two entities):**

```
Table Users
    UserID int, PK, Identity
    UserName nvarchar
    Settings nvarchar(max) or any other type
```

**Links for table splitting:**
[Using DB-First](http://www.deveducate.com/blog/post/2010/12/14/Entity-Framework-Modeling-Table-Splitting.aspx)
[Using Code-First](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for One to One then the UserSetting table should has one primary key and this key should be foreign key to the User table in the same time :

User (Table) UserID (P.K Identity int) UserName (nvarchar)
UserSetting (Table) UserSettingsID (P.K Identity int AND F.K of User.UserID)